# How to schedule quartzScheduler grails expire job again?

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

Could you please tell me what is the way to reschedule the already expire quartz job in grails application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method of QuartzScheduler for rescheduling purposes.

```
 java.util.Date rescheduleJob(java.lang.String s, java.lang.String s1, org.quartz.Trigger trigger)
```

From the Quartz source code:It deletes the Trigger with the given name, and store the new given one - which must be associated with the same job (the new trigger must have the job name & group specified) - however, the new trigger need not have the same name as the old trigger.